# Installing Outlook Addin in different computers

Tags: c#-3.0

I created a outlook add-in using visual studio 2008 and now i want to install the add-in in different computers.

Problem-: After installing the add-in, the outlook does not shows any thing and if i visit trust center-> add-in-> it shows there and after enabling it, it got disable automatically.

Using outlook 2007, windows XP, .NET 3.5 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook disables its add-ins if they fail to load or crash Outlook.
To enable your add-in try to change the following values in registry:

- HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\<add-in
  name>\LoadBehavior = 0x3

  or
- HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\<add-in
  name>\LoadBehavior = 0x3